# Extração de dados de um calendário com Python e Beautifulsoup (em Linux Ubuntu-like)

Tags: python, web-scraping

Amigos,

Gostaria de pegar dados em um calendário:

http://www.purebhakti.com/component/panjika

O primeiro passo seria fazer o programa escolher a time zone ( -3:00 Buenos Aires) e clicar em Submit Time Zone.

Após clicar em Submit Time Zone, selecionar a cidade (Rio de Janeiro) e clicar em Get Calendar.

Só após essas etapas, terei acesso ao calendário efetivamente para pensar em extrair as informações.

Gostaria de, pegar o evento do dia:

Por exemplo, hoje é dia 22, então imprimiria:

22 Apr 2017  : Ekādaśī, K, 06:09, Śatabhiṣā

+ŚUDDHA EKĀDAŚĪ VRATA: FASTING FOR Varūthinī EKADASI

Pensei em utilizar o Python e beautifulsoap mas aceito sugestões.

Pergunta: Como fazer o programa chegar até o calendário (após fazer a seleção do time zone e cidade automaticamente)?

Não consegui sair de:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.purebhakti.com/component/panjika'
header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                        'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                        'Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}



req = requests.get(url,headers= header)

html = req.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
```

Comment: Tem algum código inicial ?

Comment: só este. tinha esquecido de postar

Comment: Já é um começo, se naum pode soar "faz para mim" saca ? Quia apouco aparece um manjador de phyton...

Comment: Desculpe, foi erro meu.

Comment: Não acho que seja complexo, mas eu realmente não sei! Obrigado pela contribuição!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta isto:

```
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url_post = 'http://www.purebhakti.com/component/panjika'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'}
payload = {'action': 2, 'timezone': 23, 'location': 'Rio de Janeiro, Brazil        043W15 22S54     -3.00'}

req = requests.post(url_post, headers=headers, data=payload)
soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
eles = soup.select('tr td')
dates = (' '.join(d.select('b')[0].text.strip().split()) for d in eles if d.has_attr('class'))
events = (' '.join(d.text.split()) for d in eles if not d.has_attr('class'))
calendar = dict(zip(dates, events))

data_hoje = time.strftime("%d %b %Y", time.gmtime())
calendar[data_hoje] = calendar.setdefault(data_hoje, 'nenhum evento para hoje')
print(calendar[data_hoje])
```

Output do ultimo print (dia de hoje, 22 Feb 2017):

> Ekādaśī, K, 05:46, Purvāṣāḍhā +ŚUDDHA EKĀDAŚĪ VRATA: FASTING FOR Vijaya EKADASI

Há que ter muita atenção aos elementos HTML que queremos, neste caso queremos os `<td>`, se tiverem a class `date` é uma data (chave do dicionário) senão é o evento (valor correspondente)

Neste caso as keys do nosso dicionário vão ser o texto que está dentro de `<b>` que por sua vez este está dentro de um `td` que tenha o atributo class

Comment: Muito obrigado. Como passar para o print, imprimir print (calendar['data de hoje']) ? Tentei com from datetime import datetime mas nao deu certo!

Comment: Ha vou ver isso @EdS , só um sec

Comment: Muito obrigado. Desculpe o trabalho.

Comment: Sem problema eu devia ter lido esse pormenor na pergunta @EdS, mas enganou-se porque hoje é dia 22 Feb, e não 22 Abr :P

Comment: Muito bom. Obrigado. Vou estudar o codigo e depois marco como resolvido.

Comment: Ok @EdS, sem problema. Ainda bem que resolveste. O importante é mesmo perceber os elementos html que queres e como retirar informação

Comment: @EdS, editei a ultima por achar que assim fica melhor... com defaultDict: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm

Comment: DIa 10 Apr 2017 ocorrem varios eventos, como imprimir cada um em uma linha diferente?

Comment: @EdS em vez de `' '.join(d.text.split())`, deixa só `d.text`

Comment: Estou tentando modificar o seguinte: imagine que desejo imprimir o evento que ocorrerá daqui a X dias, por exemplo, 4 dias.  futuro = date.fromordinal(hj.toordinal()+4). O problema é que este codigo gera data assim: 2017-02-26. O que fazer?

Comment: @EdS isso é uma pergunta à parte. Agora não consigo ajudar porque não estou no computador. Mas tenta, `time.strftime("%d %b %Y", time.gmtime(time.time() + (3600 * 24 * 4)))`, para mais 4 dias a partir de hoje